# Bootable USB fails mid boot

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup

This may be obvious but I have attempted to boot from a bootable USB on my MacBook Pro (2011, running Lion 10.7.5), the USB *does* boot but fails to finish the full boot process (it is a Ubuntu derived bootable linux USB).

In terms of what happens during boot, well it goes to the grub options and after selecting, it will start to boot, get to a certain point and then "stop" and hang with nothing on the screen.

I have used this same USB to boot into other, newer MacBooks with success.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

NOTE: The usb is formatted FAT32

Comment: Details are important, like Mac model/year, which distro of Linux, what happens during the boot, any system messages you are seeing.  There's virtually no way to diagnose this with the severe lack of information.

Comment: @Allen Yes, you are right. But like I said, there were not many details to give. However, I added an edit to the question.

Comment: @Mikolaj you still didn't answer many of the questions Allan asked. You'll need to provide the Mac model and any log messages before the "hang", as well as the exact distro.

Comment: @IronCraftMan I understood the question. 100% But I think you should re-read the original question that I asked. If I am booting from a *bootable* USB, it will not be saving any log files (unless I am really missing something!).

Comment: PS: The only reason I have asked is because I have been unable to figure it out AT ALL. Despite attempts. If I had log files, I would have already figured it out myself.

Comment: burn linux onto a CD! as you have been instructed by the provider of Linux! thats how the mac prefers it, and it will always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacBook Pro before 2012 don't really support USB boot (that's why when you install Bootcamp on these machine it requires the Windows CD). You needs to burn it into a CD, if you want to make changes to that Linux, you have to install the system into a partition of your 2011 Mac hard drive, then make change to that partition.

Comment: Pre-2012 MBP "don't really" support USB boot?  That's like "kinda being pregnant";  either it supports it or it doesn't.  Seeing that my 2010 MBP boots from USB just fine, I have to ask "where did you get this info?"

Comment: @Allan What OS is on your USB drive

Comment: [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org) , El Cap (10.11), Yosemite (10.10), Mavericks (10.9)

Comment: @Allan Because all of my Pre-2012 Machine can't boot into a Linux USB drive while newer ones all could